# Magnetic field around a magnetic dipole and circular current loop

Tags: magnetic-fields, dipole

Qualitatively, how does the magnetic field around an ideal dipole compare with the magnetic field around a circular current loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Qualitatively, how does the magnetic field around an ideal dipole compare with the magnetic field around a circular current loop?

As one moves away from a circular current loop, in any direction, the magnetic field more and more closely approximates that of an ideal magnetic dipole.

Comment: What is the formula for magnetic field around a dipole?